# Android UsageStatsManager works in activity, but returns empty in bounded service

Tags: android

I have an activity and bounded service. In activity.OnCreate(), I print the usagestats and it works fine. I tried too many things to get the usagestats in boundedservice, but I could not. Here are some scenarios, I tested

1)Activity.Oncreate: calls **usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(  startTime, endTime);** and I get a map filled with the usageStats. Good

2)Background service, after completing OnStartCommand periodically, calls the  **usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(  startTime, endTime);** and it gets empty map. ***Bad***. (here I used the context that is coming out of bounded service)

3)In a desperate attempt, I used the callback from service and called the activity to invoke the same **usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(  startTime, endTime);** and it again gets the empty map. **Bad**. (here I used the context that is coming out of activity)

In all the above scenarios, I verified on my phone that the app is having permissions to get the app usage data.

I have following entry in androidmanifest.xml to start the service

```
 <service android:name="CENSORED.main.SmartBoundedService"  />
```

Why are the scenarios in bullets 2 and 3 returning empty usagestats? I feel like I tried too many things and may have lacked some conceptual understanding on how the bounded services interact with android system services.

I have UI running on mainactivity and all logic running in bounded service. Are there any limitations/guidelines on how bounded versus intent services should get android system service (I am assuming none)

Any discussion, even if it doesnt answer my question directly, would be informative and appreciated

Comment: please don't post real packages of applications. I have cenored it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Forground or background Service time is not tracked by android. However, since API Level 29, the foreground service time is tracked through:

```
UsageStats.getTotalTimeForegroundServiceUsed()
```

This is not available before API Level 29.

You will need to track the time of utilization by yourself through events.